# Lazy load multiple defaultly exported components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I have a component library with multiple icon components that I am wanting to bring into my new project but I am wanting to lazily load, but I'm not 100% sure on how to go about this.

The icon components are all default exports from their respective component files.

I have seen the standard way of lazy loading a component:

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```

however, the examples I see like this are simply from within the same project... Nothing seems to show from an external lib as I am wanting to do.

My component lib has a structure like:

```
.
└── My-Library/
    └── src/
        └── icons/
            └── svg/
                ├── person.ts
                ├── car.ts
                └── ...
```

with each icon component having a structure like:

```
export default Person = () => (
    <svg>
        ...
    </svg>
)
```

Is it possible to import these?